# Apache POI sum is not evaluated

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Hi I am using Apache POI 2.5.1

FormulaEvaluator is not supported in this version.

When open excel sheet it display like below:

[image]

But after double click in cell or click in formula bar evaluates the formula.

Please provide solution to this!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POI 2.5.1 was released on the 29th of February, 2004. That's over 8 years ago! If you look at the [POI ChangeLog](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html) then you'll see there has been a huge number of improvements and fixes since then. You really need to upgrade!

Once you have upgraded to a release from this decade(!), you can then follow the [formula calculation instructions](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) on the [POI website](http://poi.apache.org/) to either recalculate the values yourself, or force Excel to do it on load.

Answer (score 0):

((HSSFSheet) sheet).setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);   - apache poi 3.1 FINAL